# Pulse text inserted, changed or removed when undoing and redoing

Tags: undo, overlays, undo-tree-mode

I heard about [`pulse.el`](https://fossies.org/linux/emacs/lisp/cedet/pulse.el) recently on [r/emacs](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/jxlsms/highlighting_yanked_region_using_pulseel/) and thought of using it to highlight the chunks of text inserted, removed or changed on undoing and redoing edits, just like [`evil-goggles`](https://github.com/edkolev/evil-goggles#preview) [used to](https://github.com/edkolev/evil-goggles/issues/20) do:

[image]
 <sup>*There's another neat thing that `evil-goggles` used to do, using different colors for different type of changes (insert, delete or edit).*</sup>

My problem is that while `pulse.el` has a function that looks like it could be used to this end, `pulse-momentary-highlight-region`, I don't know how to find the two arguments it requires, which are the points where the chunk of text involved in the undo/redo begins and ends.

Comment: Having previously written a fork of the `undo-tree` library, I am somewhat familiar with that original library.  Inasmuch as your question does not specifically relate to `undo-tree`, however, I am hesitant to do more at this time besides leave a comment....  Does your question relate to `undo-tree` only, or does it relate to the default built-in undo/redo feature, or does it relate to something called `evil-goggles`?  Or, perhaps, do you believe that one solution will fit all -- i.e., a one size fits all approach?  What version of Emacs are you using?

Comment: Here is a link to a recent thread on reddit that seems somewhat similar:  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/jxlsms/highlighting_yanked_region_using_pulseel/

Comment: Hello @lawlist, I use `undo-tree` and an `undo-tree`-specific solution would be just as good. To be honest, I was hoping in a more versatile solution because I want to apply it to keyboard macros as well, but I can see about that separately. I'm using GNU Emacs 26.3 but I'm going to upgrade to v27 in a couple of days.

Comment: My first guess at an approach would be to type `M-x find-function RET primitive-undo RET`, and copy that function over to a `*scratch*` buffer.  Then look at the sections of code `(insert string)` that appear in a couple of locations.  That looks like a potential entry point to apply the overlays to the applicable string.  However, I haven't tested any of that ... This approach will probably suffice for both the default built-in Emacs 26 and/or 27, as well as the stock version of `undo-tree`.  That being said, I am still a little reluctant to open a Pandora's Box by writing up an answer ...

Comment: You will need to make decisions regarding how to handle text that has been *removed* as you really cannot highlight something that is not there any more ...

Comment: Regarding the text to be removed I thought it was possible to handle it before it was actually erased from the buffer. Anyway, I'm going to tinker with `primitive-undo` but I'll take it easy and so I I'd rather not open the box for the time being... I didn't expect it to be so involved.

Comment: Just before the section `(delete-region beg end)` in `primitive-undo` is likely the location you may wish to use to handle highlighting text before removal ... [again, I haven't tested that hypothesis].  You can keep the same name of `primitive-undo` and just place that revised function in your `.emacs` / `init.el` file and Emacs will use your updated function in lieu of the buit-in function.  You can also change all of the calls to `primitive-undo` within `undo-tree.el` to something like `my-primitive-undo` and place that new function with the new name inside your `.emacs` / `init.el` file.

Comment: There's a new package on MELPA that does what I want. Well, almost, because it doesn't highlight the full chunk of text when undoing or redoing removes one, but it's close. https://github.com/minad/goggles